# Prove $27abc + 10(a^2+b^2+c^2)^{\frac{3}{2}} \geq 6(a+b+c)(a^2+b^2+c^2)$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality, cauchy-schwarz-inequality

> Let $a,b,c$ be real numbers. Prove that $$27abc + 10(a^2+b^2+c^2)^{\frac{3}{2}} \geq 6(a+b+c)(a^2+b^2+c^2).$$

My work:
I started with some Cauchy-Schwarz on the $(a^2+b^2+c^2)^{3/2}$ to get similar to $(a+b+c)(a^2+b^2+c^2)$ but I don't know what to do next.

Comment: I started with some cauchy-schwarz on the $(a^2+b^2*c^2)^{3/2}$ to get similar to $(a+b+c)(a^2+b^2+c^2)$ but i don’t know how to do next

Answer (score 2):

Your problem reduces to showing that
$$
10(a^2+b^2+c^2)^{3/2}\geq 6(a+b+c)(a^2+b^2+c^2)-27abc.$$
Since the left side is nonnegative, then after squaring it suffices to show that
$$
100(a^2+b^2+c^2)^3\geq (6(a+b+c)(a^2+b^2+c^2)-27abc)^2.
$$
Expanding the cube and the square, and moving everything to the left, this reduces to showing that a certain homogeneous degree 6 polynomial in $a,b,c$ is nonnegative.

There are algorithms for finding the minimum of such polynomials, when such minimums exist.  See [this paper](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1023/A:1024664432540) for instance.

Here is an *ad hoc* method of dealing with this specific polynomial.  Since it is homogeneous, it suffices to treat the cases when $a=0,1,-1$, after scaling as necessary.  When $a=0$, the polynomial factors nicely, and it can easily be seen to be nonnegative.  When $a=\pm 1$, you now have degree 6 polynomials in two variables.  Taking the partials with respect to those variables, and setting equal to zero, there are finitely many solutions. You can check that the polynomials explode at at infinity, and so any minimum has to occur as one of those solutions.

Comment: I did not downvote you. 1) I don't have access to that article. Is it an analytic solution? 2) Your answer provides solutions which are not human verifiable.

Comment: @RiverLi (1) You can request papers through interlibrary loan (or email me, and I'll give you a copy). (2) How so?  It might be painful to do (with lots of case analysis), but it is certainly human verifiable.

Comment: @RiverLi Here is an alternative solution, that is easily human verifiable.  Use a computer to write the degree 6 homogeneous polynomial I described above as a sum of squares of rational functions.  There are tools like sostools (https://www.cds.caltech.edu/sostools/) in matlab that will do it for you.

Comment: Yes, Sum of squares here is human verifiable (easily).

Answer (score 1):

WLOG, assume that $a \le b \le c$.

We split into two cases.

**Case 1**: $a < 0$

WLOG, assume that $a = -1$.
It suffices to prove that
$$-27bc + 10(1 + b^2 + c^2)^{3/2}
\ge 6(b + c - 1)(1 + b^2 + c^2)$$
or
$$-27bc + (1+b^2+c^2)\left[10\sqrt{1+b^2+c^2} - 6(b + c) + 6\right]\ge 0.$$

Since $bc \le (b + c)^2/4$ and $b^2 + c^2 \ge (b + c)^2/2$ and $10\sqrt{1+b^2+c^2} - 6(b+c)
> 10\sqrt{1 + (b + c)^2/2} - 6(b+c) \ge 0$,
it suffices to prove that
$$-27\cdot (b + c)^2/4 + [1+(b+c)^2/2]\left[10\sqrt{1+(b+c)^2/2} - 6(b + c) + 6)\right]\ge 0.$$

Letting $x = b + c$, it suffices to prove that
$$-27\cdot x^2/4 + (1+x^2/2)\left[10\sqrt{1+x^2/2} - 6x + 6)\right]\ge 0$$
or
$$10(1 + x^2/2)^{3/2} \ge 3x^3 + \frac{15}{4}x^2 + 6x - 6$$
or (squaring both sides)
$$\frac{1}{16}(56x^4 + 88x^3 + 207x^2 + 104x + 64)(x-4)^2\ge 0$$
which is true for all $x\in \mathbb{R}$.

**Case 2**: $a \ge 0$

WLOG, assume that $c = 1$. Then $0 \le a \le b \le 1$. It suffices to prove that
$$27ab + 10(a^2+b^2+1)^{3/2} \geq 6(a+b+1)(a^2+b^2+1)$$
or
$$27ab + (a^2 + b^2 + 1)\left[10\sqrt{a^2 + b^2 + 1} - 6(a + b+1)\right]\ge 0.$$

We only need to prove the case that $10\sqrt{a^2 + b^2 + 1} - 6(a + b+1) < 0$.

Using $a^2 + b^2 \le (a + b)^2$, it suffices to prove that
$$27ab + [(a + b)^2 + 1]\left[10\sqrt{a^2 + b^2 + 1} - 6(a + b+1)\right]\ge 0.$$

Using $\sqrt{1 + u} \ge 1 + u/3$ for all $u \le 2$ and $a + b \le 2$, we have $\sqrt{1 + a^2 + b^2} \ge 1 + (a^2 + b^2)/3$.
It suffices to prove that
$$27ab + [(a + b)^2 + 1]\left[10\cdot (1 + (a^2 + b^2)/3) - 6(a + b+1)\right]\ge 0. \tag{1}$$

Let $p = a + b, q = ab$. (1) is written as
$$27q + (p^2 + 1)\left[10\cdot (1 + (p^2 - 2q)/3) - 6(p+1)\right]\ge 0$$
or
$$(61 - 20p^2)q + 2(p^2+1)(5p^2-9p+6)\ge 0.$$

Since $5p^2-9p+6 > 0$, we only need to prove the case that $61 - 20p^2 < 0$. Using $q \le p^2/4$, it suffices to prove that
$$(61 - 20p^2)\cdot \frac{p^2}{4} + 2(p^2+1)(5p^2-9p+6)\ge 0$$
or
$$5p^4 - 18p^3 + \frac{149}{4}p^2 - 18p + 12 \ge 0$$
which is true all $p \in \mathbb{R}$.

We are done.